# GIT: git checkout .DS_Store error: "error: pathspec '.DS_Store' did not match any file(s) known to git."

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to remove the changes from this file .DS_Store. using git checkout but I'm getting this error:

```
git checkout .DS_Store 
error: pathspec '.DS_Store' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

When I do `git status` I get:

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .DS_Store
```

Any of you knows how checkout this file ? or if I'm doing something wrong at the moment of the checkout?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: The command says it is untracked (which it should be), so you cannot "remove the changes". But you should also add it to your `.gitignore` so it does not show up.

Answer (score 4):

You can do `git reset` or, add the `.DS_Store` file in `.gitignore` file.

*.DS_store* is a auto generated file for MacOS.

```
$ git add .
$ git reset --hard HEAD


# Or, add '.DS_store' in .gitignore file
$ nano .gitignore

# Now add '.DS_store' at the end of the '.gitignore' file
```

---

**Alternate**: one of the alternate way to clean *Untracked files* is -

```
$ git clean -df                           
# -d remove untracked directories in addition to untracked files, -f (force)
```

Comment: after I do git reset --hard HEAD, I do git status and still get (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 .DS_Store

Comment: Add the file first. `git add .` then `git reset --hard HEAD`

Comment: So... you are telling them to *add* `.DS_store` to their repository? What purpose does that serve?

Comment: If you add the `.DS_Store` file in your root `.gitignore` file then Git will ignore the file changes.

Comment: See more [Why should I use gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13675216/4133798)

Comment: I know why you add the file to `.gitignore`, I am questioning the `git add .`, which would add `.DS_store` to the staging, which you do not want to do.

Comment: `git reset` does not interact with *untracked files*. So, `git add .` take the file to staging state. Then `git reset --hard HEAD` clean the working area (back to last commit)

Comment: That still makes no sense, if `.DS_store` is *untracked*, there are no changes to deal with, and you don't want it tracked anyway. So adding it to the staging is of no benefit, and neither is the reset. One just needs to add the file to the `.gitignore` and it goes away from the warning of needing to `git add` it.

Comment: Untracked files means there is change in the file but Git does not add/commit the file before. When the file would be added once it is under version control. Also if further change occurs after added the files once, then `git status` tell you that the file is `Modified` instead `untracked`

Comment: Say, if you create a new file called `a.txt` in your repo. `git status` tells you that `a.txt` is untracked file cause it does not added/committed before (it is not under version control). After committing the `a.txt` file if you change in `a.txt` file then `git status` tells you that `a.txt` file is **Modified**

Comment: Yeah, I've been working with git for a while now. My point is that the add command is on the opposite end of the spectrum from `.gitignore`. You do one *or the other*, but not both.

Comment: Yes, Agree. Updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

GIT has excellent support for each command.

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

.DS_Store
```

Please refer the message, it clearly stating that the file .DS_Store is untracked and if you want the file to be tracked under GIT then use the following command

$ git add .DS_Store

Please refer the following image for the file status lifecycle in GIT.

[image]

For more details refer [Git Basics - Recording Changes to the Repository](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Recording-Changes-to-the-Repository)

**Checkout**

Since the GIT not tracking the file, you cannot checkout the file.
The git checkout command serves three distinct functions: checking out files, checking out commits, and checking out branches.  Checking out a file lets you see an old version of that particular file, leaving the rest of your working directory untouched

More on [git checkout](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes)